# When typing a zipcode using onkeypress an event listener waits for 5 characters then an event fires

Tags: javascript, json, dom, dom-events

I would like to have a zipcode input field that listens when 5 characters (numeric 0-9) are typed.

I imagine something like in JavaScript:

```
if (charCount == 5){
```

When the `charCount = 5` is fulfilled it sends a `getJSON` request and receives a JSON response from the server.

The data has an array of data where I'd like to select specific object or parameters and values within the array.

The selected object parameters and values are displayed in the DOM through radio button inputs with the appropriate text from the data labelling the inputs.

The user selects one choice, select data from the JSON string is concatenated to a base URL query string.

Then the user goes to the next page.

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *easiest* way will vary depending on who's doing it -- are you already comfortable with / using a JavaScript library for this page?  Have you looked into templating libraries to simplify the HTML creation?

```
var is_five_digits = /^\d{5}$/g; // Only match five digits
if ( is_five_digits.test(your_input) ) {
    // Execute the getJSON request 
    // if using jQuery, for example it's just:
    // $.getJSON('your.url', {zip: your_input}, callback);
    // where callback is the function you want to use to generate your list.
    // However, you'll still need an event handler to listen for change events
    // on your new radio buttons and redirect the page once the choice is made.
}
```

Things (i.e. JavaScript libraries) you may want to look into include:

### JavaScript Libraries

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), [Mootools](http://mootools.net/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/)

### Templating Solutions

[Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), and [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure/).

Comment: What is the /^\d{5}$/g; ? I can see that it is saying match only 5 digits but I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: @ectype -- `//` is the regular expression literal construct.  Regular expressions are a powerful way of expressing a pattern that you want to match.  SEE: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

listen to the text changed event on the textbox, then in the event handler, check the length (as you suggest). If the length matches, then do your JSON request.